# I'm trying to make a program that adds a user's input and adds 2 to it, don't understand errors

Tags: rust

```
use std::io; 

fn main() {
    let mut number_to_add = String::new();
    
    println!("what do you wanna add to two");

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut number_to_add);

    let number_to_add: u32 = number_to_add.trim().parse();  {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err() => continue,
    };

    let mut result = 2 + number_to_add;

    println!("result is {}", result);
}
```

Here is the error output:

```
error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `=>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
12 |         Ok(num) => num,
   |                 ^^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:30
   |
11 |     let number_to_add: u32 = number_to_add.trim().parse();  {
   |                        ---   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u32`, found enum `Result`
   |                        |
   |                        expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected type `u32`
              found enum `Result<_, _>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `mather` due to 2 previous errors
```

Before I get asked, yes, I have read the explanation with rustc and I do not understand it. I know that it's probably expecting a number, but aren't the `.trim()` and `.parse()` supposed to turn the user inputted string into a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "open", or `.unwrap()` values in Rust which are wrapped or may result in a `None`.

```
use std::io; 

fn main() {
    let mut number_to_add = String::new();
    println!("what do you wanna add to two");

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut number_to_add);

    let number_to_add = number_to_add.trim().parse::<u32>().unwrap();

    let result = 2 + number_to_add;

    println!("result is {}", result);
}
```

[Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e34053d3358d817d14500d97f4f3dfca) a playground with a hardcoded value for the input.

Or, if you want to keep your `Ok`/`Err` block, it needs a `match`:

```
let number_to_add: i32 = match number_to_add.trim().parse::<u32>() {
    Ok(number) => number.try_into().unwrap(),
    Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
};

let result = 2 + number_to_add;

println!("result is {}", result);
```

Updated playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9da146ee04403e8744408048ca14082).

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a "dumb question", I'm still learning, but what does it mean for a value to be wrapped?

Comment: @nulla The value is in a Result type (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/).  `unwrap` gets the underlying value

Comment: No dumb questions. Above, `parse::<u32>` returns a `Result` which can be one of two values: in this case a `u32` or an `Err`. Unwrap opens the `Result` to access the value.